# yum local install to install a package with its dependency

Tags: centos, centos7, yum

I have downloaded a package with it's dependency and want to install a package with dependency. Even though i have download in local folder it's checking for online.

`sudo yum -y --disablerepo=* localinstall autoconf-2.69-11.el7.noarch.rpm`

I am trying above command but failed to load it's dependency that is there in same folder.

Thanks,
Hare

Comment: Install both rpms in the same command.

Answer (score 21):

Inside the local directory where you have all the downloaded RPMs, do this:

```
 sudo yum --disablerepo=* localinstall *.rpm
```

OR

```
 sudo yum --disablerepo=* localinstall foo.rpm bar.rpm baz.rpm
```

Since you have downloaded all the dependencies to a single directory, you can also use `rpm` to install those:

```
 sudo rpm -Uvvh *.rpm --test
```

`--test` does a dry-run. Remove it to install on disk.

Comment: to get all the packages,

```bash
yum --downloadonly --downloaddir=/root/pkgdir install <package-name>
```

this downloads all the rpms to one folder `/root/pkgdir`.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the solution provide by iamauser is very great (and I am using it all the time), I wish to give you an other way to do it.

It exists yum-downloader command which doing basically the same thing for you.

```
# yumdownloader <package> --resolve
```

You just have to download it first :

```
# yum install yum-utils
```

Overall, I suggest you to read this article from Red Hat company site's which details everything about those two methods :
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10154